# how to filter queryset based on Datefield in django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I need to filter queryset based on today/tommorows date 
and the field available is a **date field** not **datetime field**

I am using custom manager for providing filtered result

```
class CallbackReqManager(models.Manager):
def get_queryset(self):
    return super().get_queryset().filter()

def callbacktoday(self):
    today=date.today

    print(today)
    return self.filter(prefereddate=today)


class CallbackReq(models.Model):

    name    =   models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email   =   models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    query   =   models.CharField(max_length=150)
    preferedtime = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    prefereddate = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    requestedon  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    attended  =   models.BooleanField(default=False)  #   whether call back is met

    objects =   CallbackReqManager()
```

but I am getting

```
TypeError:  match = date_re.match(value)

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: date.today returns a function.you're filtering against a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to write like this

```
today = date.today()
```

Let me know if some error still occurs.

Comment: thanks a lot , your answer solved my problem, also after looking at trace I got something like <built-in method close of file object at 0x007E6AE0> when not using parenthesis, and came across https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-forgetting-parentheses/

Answer (score 1):

You can add to new managers to your models, one for filtring by today's date and the other is by tomorrow's data. Here is an example

```
from datetime import date, timedalte
from django import models

class FilterByToday(models.Manager):
def get_queryset(self):
    """Filtering by today's date"""
    return super().get_queryset().filter(
        prefereddate=date.today()
    )

class FilterByTomorrow(models.Manager):
    """
    filtering by tomorrow's date
    where: date.today() + timedelta(days=1)
    is: Today + 1 day
    """
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(
            prefereddate=date.today() + timedalte(days=1)
        )


class CallbackReq(models.Model):

    name    =   models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email   =   models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    query   =   models.CharField(max_length=150)
    preferedtime = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    prefereddate = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    requestedon  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    attended  =   models.BooleanField(default=False)  #   whether call back is met
    # You can keep your default objects manager
    objects =   models.Manager()
    # Today's manager
    objects_today = FilterByToday()
    # Tomorrow's manager
    objects_tomorrow = FilterByTomorrow()
```

So, in your next code you can use, for example:

```
# Return all the Model's records without using the custom managers
instance = CallbackReq.objects.all()
# Return all Model's records by filtering them by today's date
instance = CallbackReq.objects_today.all()
# Return all Model's records by filtering them by tomorrow's date
instance = CallbackReq.objects_tomorrow.all()
```

For more informations visit the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset)